# Accessing URL from Oracle view

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to get the HTTP response from URL inside the Oracle view ?

**Example :**

```
SELECT 
  ACCOUNT_ID,
  URL -> TEST_PAGE.COM/<ACCOUNT_ID>,
  STATUS_CODE -> TO IDICATE IF TEST_PAGE.COM/<ACCOUNT_ID> RETURNS 404 OR OK STATUS

FROM
   ALL_ACCOOUNTS
```

I need to check somehow if the URL exist for the given account id .

Comment: you should look into utl_http.begin_request and utl_http.get_response

Comment: The latency on that query is going to be huge if you have to go a dynamically check that every page exists.

Comment: It doesnt need to be invoked 'life' . I am going to extract that info and refresh weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this to test out URLs. It will return the HTTP status code from the response. If there is an Oracle error that is thrown in the procedure, the error code will be returned, but they will be easy to identify since it will be a negative number. You can modify the code within the `test_url` procedure if you want to set timeouts, authentication, or anything special for your requests.

```sql
WITH
    FUNCTION test_url (p_url VARCHAR2)
        RETURN NUMBER
    AS
        l_http_request    UTL_HTTP.req;
        l_http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp;
    BEGIN
        l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (p_url);
        l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (l_http_request);
        UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
        RETURN l_http_response.status_code;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
            RETURN (SQLCODE);
    END;
SELECT 'http://neverssl.com' AS url, test_url ('http://neverssl.com') AS status_code FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'http://google.com' AS url, test_url ('http://google.com') AS status_code FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'localhost' AS url, test_url ('localhost') AS status_code FROM DUAL;
```

For your table, you would want the query to look like this

```sql
WITH
    FUNCTION test_url (p_url VARCHAR2)
        RETURN NUMBER
    AS
        l_http_request    UTL_HTTP.req;
        l_http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp;
    BEGIN
        l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (p_url);
        l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (l_http_request);
        UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
        RETURN l_http_response.status_code;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
            RETURN (SQLCODE);
    END;
SELECT aa.account_id, aa.url, test_url (aa.url) AS status_code
  FROM all_accounts aa;
```